# Get response from API with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, api

I'd like to type some stuff into an input field and then get a response from the API if the value exist or not.

The API will response with a true/ false value if the zipcode (12345) exist. http://192.168.100.100:8887/public?zipcode=12345

And here's my code so far:

```
$(function() {

    $('.positiveMessage, .negativeMessage').hide()
    $('#submitBtn').on('click', function() {
        var $zipcode = document.getElementById('searchZipCode').value
        $.getJSON({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://192.168.100.100:8887/public?zipcode=' + $zipCode,
            success: result => {
                //Goes through the array
                $.each(result, function(i, info) {
                    $('body').append(info + '')
                })
            }
        })
    })
})
```

As you can see I'd like to manipulate the API by adding a variable in the link.

Comment: you are giving a local ip ;)

Comment: Ops! I will write out the JSON!

Comment: you are looping through a boolean ?

Comment: Yes. Only true or false

Answer (score 1):

I added a simple if else statement and it worked out alright. Although I don't know if I should use this method or not:

```
//Checks keys
if (result) {
    $('.positiveMessage').show()
} else {
    $('.negativeMessage').show()
}
```

Comment: yes, that's a better solution than looping through a boolean

Comment: Alright! Thanks for replying so quickly Peter. I really appreciate it. Btw, when I search for a value that doesn't exist my `.negativeMessage` shows, but when I search for a value that do exit my `.positiveMessage` shows too, but my other message don't disappear. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You've got some ES6 in there (the left arrow in your success function) that might not work as you're expecting. You're also using getElementById when you've already got jQuery.

It's hard to answer without the API feed but this should help you at least get a response. Use console.log to print what returns from the API, then you should be able to traverse to the data you need.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.positiveMessage, .negativeMessage').hide()
    $('#submitBtn').on('click', function() {
        var zipCode = $('#searchZipCode').val();
        $.getJSON({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://192.168.100.100:8887/public?zipcode=' + zipCode,
            success: function(result){
                if (result) {
                    $('.positiveMessage').show()
                    $('.negativeMessage').hide()
                } else {
                    $('.positiveMessage').hide()
                    $('.negativeMessage').show()
                }
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick :

```
$('.positiveMessage').show();
var time_hide = 1000; // in ms
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.positiveMessage').hide();
}, time_hide);
```

Comment: Smart idea, but I wonder if a component that last until a user has search again i better. *thinking face*